# Opacity is not changing when hover on the element?

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

I have a div whose opacity is 0 initially.
Now, there is a list element on which hover I would like to change the opacity of div to 1.

I tried the below code but it's not working.

```css
.otherlinks {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 1px);
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid var(--main-color);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: var(--main-transition);
  -webkit-transition: var(--main-transition);
  -moz-transition: var(--main-transition);
  -ms-transition: var(--main-transition);
  -o-transition: var(--main-transition);
}

.head-list .link:hover .otherlinks {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="head-list">
  <li><a href="articles">articles</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery">gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="features">features</a></li>
  <li class="otherlink"><a href="other-links">other links</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="otherlinks">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://ps.w.org/ap-mega-menu/assets/icon-256x256.png" alt="megamenu">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems some other styles are overriding your current styles. Because if you will remove all anchor tags and keep your code normal, everything will work. For example, if you try this, things will work- 
`<div class="otherlink">other links</div>
    <div class="otherlinks">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://ps.w.org/ap-mega-menu/assets/icon-256x256.png" alt="megamenu">
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: And at css side, if you do this- `.otherlink:hover + .otherlinks {
  opacity: 1;
}`

Comment: That is only if what you hover is a sibling

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can use JS to do this.
I used two events `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` on the `li` element to toggle the opacity of div which has class `otherlinks`.

```js
function changeOpacity(opacity) {
 let el = document.querySelector(".otherlinks");
 el.style.opacity = opacity;
}
```

```css
.otherlink {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.otherlinks{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid var(--main-color);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: var(--main-transition);
    -webkit-transition: var(--main-transition);
    -moz-transition: var(--main-transition);
    -ms-transition: var(--main-transition);
    -o-transition: var(--main-transition);
}
```

```html
<ul class="head-list">
  <li><a href="articles">articles</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery">gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="features">features</a></li>
  <li 
    class="otherlink" 
    onmouseover="changeOpacity(1)" 
    onmouseleave="changeOpacity(0)"
  >
    <a href="other-links">HOVER ME</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="otherlinks">
 <div class="image">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="megamenu">
 </div>
</div>
```